# Lua protobuf. pb package sends wrong encoded message if this message is empty

Tags: lua, protocol-buffers

I've got a problem with using lua pb package.
pb.encode function encodes protobuf message in a wrong way if this message is described so:

```
message MyMessage
{
}
```

When I got the encoding message on server it differs from one that has at least one field.

What's wrong with pb ? Thanks

Comment: The only correct encoding of `MyMessage` is: zero bytes (literally nothing, zip, nada). What are you seeing that makes you think it is wrong? Protobuf doesn't include any header info on a root message, so without context of what *exactly* you're seeing, it is kinda hard to know what's going on here. It is of course trivially true that we expect a message with one field to look different to a message with zero fields - or indeed, from a message with two fields. But without more context, it isn't obvious what you're actually doing.

Comment: I mean that if we have two kinds of messages - message A {} and message A { int32 idx}, and we encode both messages with pb.encode without setting any fields, then we got different byte array in encoded message: for first one: 08 04, for second one: D2 03 00 08 04

Comment: By the way I use A message as oneof in other message:
message MyMessages
{
    oneof data
    {
          A mes_a = 1;
          B mes_b = 2;
     }
}

Comment: "D2 03 00" is "field 58 of type string (which just means length-prefixed; it doesn't imply text) with an empty payload"; "08 04" is "field 1 of type varint with value 4 (raw) or 2 (zigzag)"; it is hard to compare that directly to your message because you don't *have* a field 58, but if you have an *actual concrete example* of both payload and model, I'll happily walk you through what is happening.